# Openshift: how to import MySQL driver to the tomcat/lib directory

Tags: mysql, tomcat, tomcat7, driver, openshift

I would like to connect my web application (running on tomcat 7) to MySQL (v5.6.20). It is ok if I include the driver mysql-connector-java-5.1.31-bin.jar into my web application. But  would like to have it for all my apps. On my local computer, I put the file in tomcat/lib and everything is fine.

How to do the same with openshift? Is it a bad idea to do so?

I am a total beginner. What I do to upload my application (war files) is

> git add --all
>
> git commit --m "text"
>
> git push

Thanks a lot for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two KB articles from the Help Center that I think will help you get going, the first shows how to use the pre-configured database connections that come with each of the Java containers on OpenShift (https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202399720-How-to-use-the-pre-configured-MySQLDS-and-PostgreSQLDS-data-sources-in-the-Java-cartridges), They are very easy to use.

The second shows you how to include external libraries (jar files) inside your application without using maven (https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202399730-How-to-include-libraries-jar-files-in-your-java-application-without-using-Maven).

A third option, if you are using a Maven based project (similar to the default applications that come with the Java cartridges), is to add the mysql driver as a dependency to your pom.xml file, and it will be loaded into the correct place in your application when you do a git push.  If you want to go that route, I think that this article will help: http://www.java-tutorial.ch/core-java-tutorial/mysql-with-java-and-maven-tutorial

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. My question is: How to include my jars in tomcat/lib/ directory instead of src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't have access to that directory, that's why I provided three other ways of doing it in my answer.